# cannot resolve symbol "setText" SherlockActionBar fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a child fragment in my application that im trying to test functionality in. The idea is that the textview will update to mimic whatever is entered into the edittext. However currently it doesn't like the setText and i have no idea why. I've checked to see whether i had missed an import and i think the widgets are defined correctly. Any advice on how to solve this problem would be great.

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WeightFragment extends SherlockFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_weight, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

EditText weight = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.weightInput);
TextView label = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.weightResult);

String result = weight.getText().toString();
label.setText(result);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code INSIDE a method, like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_weight, container, false);

    EditText weight = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.weightInput);
    TextView label = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.weightResult);

    String result = weight.getText().toString();
    label.setText(result);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Just tried this and it worked (dunno why i didnt try this in the first place haha). I'm assuming if i was to put it in the oncreate it wouldn't update everytime i changed the value in the editText. Do you have any idea how i would go about making it dynamic?

Comment: Just create a method 'updateLabel' and call it whenever you want

Comment: Can you explain why It should be inside a method?

Comment: You have to call getActivity() inside a class method, it's java basics