# TextView setText Cannot resolve type

Tags: android, textview

Im using Android Studio, trying set text to Text View but every time i do this

```
TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testView);
test.setText("fds");
```

on Android Studio i see `Cannot resolve symbol 'setText'`.
Can someone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot resolve symbol "setText" SherlockActionBar fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788681/cannot-resolve-symbol-settext-sherlockactionbar-fragment)

Comment: post your whole code, in which method you are doing this?

Comment: did you import TextView class ?

Comment: Does Android Studio offer you any suggestion to solve the problem?

Comment: Please post your entire class code here. This seems too trivial of a thing to break.

Comment: the method setText() hasn;t found inside TextView... the case may be that the class TextView is not from package "android.widget"

Comment: see the import statements

Comment: Please post the entire code here. Is it possible that you have any other "test' variable locally?

Comment: @Rasta_Man: Don't you read comments. Everyone is asking for more code. Without that no one would be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

`setText()` will accept String which you have passed, so there is no issue in that.

One possible reason for this might be you have not written your code inside `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`.

1. If it is `Activity` you need to use these lines after `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`.
2. If it is `Fragment` you need to use these lines after inflating your `view` in `onCreateView()`.

Second reason, you might be having one more `test` variable of different type like String or something else

Comment: The reason is that it wasnt in onCreate(). Now i have other problem. I dont get any problem but text in Label doesnt change. There is not much to copy cuz i just try do only this atm so i have auto generated code with those 2 lines. Sorry for my English ;) hope u understand.

Comment: @Rasta_Man: Don't you read comments. Everyone is asking for more code. Without that no one would be able to help.

Comment: Please accept this answer if it solved the problem you posted. Post your other problem as a new question as well instead of asking via comments.